# How to get values from selected row in DataGrid for Windows Form Application?

Tags: c#, winforms

Title is pretty self-explanatory.  I've got a DataGrid for a Windows Form Application, and I want to be able to store the values of a selected row.  What is the easiest way to go about doing this?

I have found this chunk of code as an example in my search, but doesn't work when the DataGrid is sorted differently:

```
private void grdPatients_CurrentCellChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int row = grdPatients.CurrentRowIndex;

        grdPatients.Select(row);

        ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {

            arrayList.Insert(i, (patientsDS.Tables["PatientList"].Rows[row].ItemArray.GetValue(i)));

        }

        textBox1.Text = "" + arrayList[0];

        textBox2.Text = "" + arrayList[1];

        textBox3.Text = "" + arrayList[2];
    }
```

Comment: The question you're asking and the answer given are completely different. Windows.Forms DataGrid does not support these actions, and you're asking about a DataGrid and not a DataGridView.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

#### Description

Assuming i understand your question.

You can get the selected row using the `DataGridView.SelectedRows` Collection. If your DataGridView allows only one selected, have a look at my sample.

> **DataGridView.SelectedRows** Gets the collection of rows selected by the user.

#### Sample

```
if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count != 0)
{
    DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0];
    row.Cells["ColumnName"].Value
}
```

#### More Information

- [MSDN - DataGridView.SelectedRows Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedrows.aspx)

Comment: The DataGrid and DataGridView are different beasts. DataGrids are column oriented as where DatagridViews are row oriented. This question is about DataGrids so it would a be a good idea to note that for the code above to work that @AlexThompson would need to switch from the grid to the GridView.

Comment: Some of us are stuck using DataGrids... Is this even accomplishable with a datagrid?

Answer (score 5):

You could just use

```
DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["ColumnName"].Value
```

Comment: I had to use:  dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString()

Answer (score 0):

For multiple choise use:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
{
    // your code        
}
```