# Create Save And Load Functionality For A Winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0, save

I have a winform with 5 text boxes and 2 data grids.  I need a way of being able to press a button (or adding a menu at the top with a file button and select save from there) and save all of the values to a file that the user selects location/name for.  Then I need a button (or again a menu option) to load the file that was previously saved and all the values from the "save" will be generated on screen so that it looks as if you just input all values.

How is this achieved in VS2017?

Comment: this is a generic question. depends on the data type. usually you serialization is the easiest way.

Comment: SO you want the whole piece of code? He He Smart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You describe your problem and your answer already. You can just straight forward implement like that: Save the data to a file, then when press the `Button 2`, load data from that file to form.

Other approach, you can have global variable, when press `Button 1`, you save data to that variable, then when `Button 2` pressed, you load this variable's value to form.

```
public class UserData
{
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your form:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            static List<UserData> savedData;
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                savedData = new List<UserData>();
            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
//This is for example only, you get data then save it like this
                savedData.Add(new UserData
                {
                    Location = "US",
                    Name = "Boston"
                });
                savedData.Add(new UserData
                {
                    Location = "US",
                    Name = "Texas"
                });

            }

            private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
//This is for example only, you WRITE your own business here
                foreach (var item in savedData)
                {
                    label1.Text = item.Location;
                    label2.Text = item.Name;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: you'd better write fully working code, to prevent downvotes

Comment: How do I actually save to a file?

Comment: @LeiYang: Thanks, I updated my answer.

Comment: Yohan: I believe you can easily find Saving to a file tutorial on the internet. This is for example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-write-to-a-text-file

Comment: @zzT - I know how to write text or sql results to a file, but I was unclear on how to read the values from my datagrids/text boxes to write to the text file.

Comment: Yohan: You also can find tutorial like below for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049937/how-to-get-values-from-selected-row-in-datagrid-for-windows-form-application 
Which solution has you tried? Any issue?

Comment: Downvote to answer (And question) by me. Code might be working, but in my opinion the question should not have been "answered" since there was no personal effort - Just lazy asking for code and an answer like this confirms that SO is a coding service.

Comment: @Luke : I firstly gave him an idea, but Lei Yang asked for a fully working code, so i wrote it up then. Thank you very much for your comment, I noted for further questions/answers.