# How to get values from selected row in DataGrid?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

All I found is about `DataGridView` and have tried some event handlers and I'm stuck now.

Assuming I have DataGrid like below :

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("Code", typeof(String));
dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(String));
gridData.DataSource = dt;
```

How I capture `onClick` event with `SelectedRows["ID"]`

This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049937/how-to-get-values-from-selected-row-in-datagrid-for-windows-form-application) works for `DataGridView` but not with DataGrid.

Comment: What .NET version are you using?

Comment: @CryogenicNeo : .NET Framework 4.6.1

Comment: The `SelectedCells` property is available in this version of .NET, it must be possible.

Comment: @CryogenicNeo : Sadly not for Windows Forms. Yes for WPF.

Comment: From [MSDN on the DataGrid control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx) "The DataGridView control replaces and adds functionality to the DataGrid control; however, the DataGrid control is retained for both backward compatibility and future use, if you choose." I think your best bet is to use a DataGridView instead.

Comment: @Sudsy1002 : I hope I can, but this is old project and Im still struggling to convert other functions to be compatible with VS2017, need really much time to convert all DataGrid to DataGridView. That is my last option if this DataGrid really can't have that function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the property `SelectedCells` of that DataGrid. That property returns to you an collection of current selected cells and you can iterate over that collection using a `foreach` loop

Supposing that you want to get the values as strings, this code can be usefull:

```
// This is the list where the values will be stored. Now it's empty.
List<string> values = new List<string>();

// Whit this 'foreach' we iterate over 'gridData' selected cells.
foreach (DataGridCellInfo x in gridData.SelectedCells)
{
    // With this line we're storing the value of the cells as strings
    // in the previous list.
    values.Add(x.Item.ToString());
}
```

Then you can later make use of the stored values at your `onClick()` method.

> You can see the following Microsoft MSDN site:
>
> [DataGrid.SelectedCells Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.selectedcells(v=vs.110).aspx)
>
> [DataGridCellInfo Structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcellinfo(v=vs.110).aspx)
>
> [DataGridCellInfo.Item Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcellinfo.item(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: `SelectedCells` just available in `DataGridView` not in `DataGrid`

Comment: The Microsoft MSDN show that it has: [DataGrid.SelectedCells Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.selectedcells(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: thanks cryo, but this is become weird now when I added the assembly, it return error `'DataGrid' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid' and 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid'` ... I will take a look on this and will update it asap. Thank You.

Comment: The class `DataGrid` must be in both assemblies, you must specify the assembly by adding `System.Windows.Forms.` or `System.Windows.Controls.` at the `DataGrid` declaration when you specify the class.

Comment: ok, this `SelectedCells` property is for WPF not Windows Form.